# MySQL Ensure All genders are present in the output

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, output

My problem is that I have two tables i will show you in a sec, then i have to print both genders if a pacient vist for the first time then the count sums 1, if its subsequent the count sums 1 and so on for example i have this imaginary tables:

Table Pacient

```
---------------------
id|    name     |sex|
01|    george   |m  |
02|    laura    |f  |
03|    holly    |f  |
04|    bill     |m  |
05|    gene     |m  |
06|    elizabeth|f  | 
---------------------
```

Table Consulting

```
------------------------
id|diagnostic|id_pacient
01| random   |01
02| random   |02
03| random   |04
04| random   |01
05| random   |04
06| random   |03
07| random   |06
08| random   |05
09| random   |03
------------------------
```

So Far i have this mysql Query:

```
select
  sex, 
  sum(visits = 1) single_visit, 
  sum(visits > 1) subsequent
from (select p.sex, count(*) as visits
      from pacient p
      join consulting c on p.id=c.id_pacient
      group by c.id_pacient) x
```

The result from own database:

```
-------------------------
sex|single_visit|subsequent
m  |24          |2(wrong value)
-------------------------
```

The problem is that only one gender is shown as above, and not the two of them also the *subsequent value* returned that is printed is the sum of both genders visits and the final output that I'm asking for should be like this:

PLEASE HELP:Final and correct output(from my own database):

```
-------------------------
sex|single_visit |subsequent
m  |24           | 1
f  |0            | 1
-------------------------
```

Comment: Add a `group by clause` at the end as `.....)x group by sex`

Comment: OMG that was so close seriously my mind went off for so many times i tried it, thank you Sir, if you add the correct answer i will check it as correct thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `group by` at the end as

```
select
  sex, 
  sum(visits = 1) single_visit, 
  sum(visits > 1) subsequent
from (select p.sex, count(*) as visits
      from pacient p
      join consulting c on p.id=c.id_pacient
      group by c.id_pacient) x
   group by sex
```